# UnwindThread(size_t): Timed out waiting for signal handler to get (server) is not responding. Waited 10002ms for MotionEvent)

Tags: java, android

bool BacktraceCurrent::UnwindThread(size_t): Timed out waiting for the signal handler to get context data.
11:01:18.015  I  Wrote stack traces to tombstoned
11:01:18.066  E  ANR in
Reason: Input dispatching timed out (8274456 (server) is not responding. Waited 10002ms for MotionEvent)